# Classic banking task

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I think this is a usual task in banking area.
I need to fill **'Income'** column by previous values from **'Outcome'**. But every 'Outcome' value calculated like **Outcome** = **Income** + **Debit** - **Credit** from current row (each rows).

I guess I should use *lag()* for **'Income'**. But this creates cyclicality in calculating.

I hope this can help:

`create table account(acc_date date,income int, debit int, credit int, outcome int);
insert into account values('2021-01-01', 100,800,500,400),
('2021-02-01', null,900,1500,null),
('2021-03-01', null,1700,2000,null),
('2021-04-01', null,2100,2800,null),
('2021-05-01', null,3500,4000,null);
select * from account;`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but by using a `sum() over(`) and coalesce in concert with the `lag() over()`

```
with cte as (
Select * 
      ,OutCome = sum( isnull(Income,0)+Debit-Credit ) over (order by date)
 From YourTable
)
Select Date
      ,Income = coalesce(Income,lag(outcome,1) over (order by date))
      ,Credit
      ,Debit
      ,OutCome
 From  cte
```

Comment: Seems to work.   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f60ae5289055d599ae1b7b8067bbb80c